# Given lengths of 3 sides of a triangle, compute an average distance between the middle points of the sides

Tags: algorithm, math, euclidean-distance, triangular

I have come across a problem. The problem statement is

A team of **3 people**, is going to participate in a competition. According to the regulations of this competition, every team is given a single computer, which is located **on a triangular table**, and **three chairs**.

Team thinks that the most convenient location of participants is the one where **each of the three participants sits at his/her own side of the triangular table, and, what’s important, exactly at the middle of this side.** Of course, chairs should be put the same way.

It is important that, during the competition, the participants sit not very far one from another. The Dream Team’s captain thinks that a proper estimation of this factor is **an average distance between all the pairs of these participants.**

In the case of this competition, one have to **compute an average distance between the middle points of the sides of a triangular table**. Write a program which computes exactly this. `Note that the distance is Euclidean – that is, the distance between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is sqrt((x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2).`

**Input**

The input ﬁle contains three positive integer numbers not exceeding 100 – the lengths of sides of the table. **It is guaranteed that such a table will have a non-zero area.**

**Output**

Output the average distance between the middle points of the sides of the table, which was described in the input.

```
Examples  
Input        Output
3 4 5        2.00000000
5 5 7        2.83333333
```

I thought of one way to solve this

```
1. Assume origin as 1 point.
2. If one of the length is 3, assume the point as (3,0).
3. Now, I struck at finding 3rd coordinate
```

Is my approach, Ok?

Please, give me an algorithm to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: Yes your approach seems correct. Now just apply cosine rule to get the three angles (make sure to take care of corner cases) and you will get the thrid coordinate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a mathematical problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal thank you

Comment: @Jason, where can i post math problems, can you please suggest me

Comment: @sanapalamohanarao http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that segment, connecting middle of edge A and middle of edge B, is [half of edge C](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp10/midlinel.htm) and the same is true for other sides.

So solution is very simple - average distance for triangle with side lengths A,B,C is

```
M = (A/2 + B/2 + C/2) / 3 = 
    (A + B + C ) / 6
```

Comment: It helped me, Thank you @MBo

Comment: OMG, this was triangle congruency. Completely forgot this.